# sum of the series of certain form close to Fermat's numbers

Tags: number-theory

My question is: What is the sum of reciprocals of the numbers $2^{2^n}$.
If we achieve this we will be able to give a good bound for the sum of reciprocals of Fermat's numbers i.e. $(2^{2^n})$+1.

Comment: Which part of these two statements is a question???

Comment: @ chiranjeev: 2^2^n

Answer (score 1):

See [OEIS A$007404$](http://oeis.org/A007404) and [OEIS A$051158$](http://oeis.org/A051158). No *known* closed form exists.